# Turn complex type into entity without losing data

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We've been using a complex type `CreditCardTransaction` associated with our purchase orders. It really should have been it's own entity, and I am trying to fix this now.

How would you write a migration from this:

```
[ComplexType()]
public class CreditCardTransaction
{
    public String SomeTransactionData { get; set; }
}
```

into this entity:

```
public class CreditCardTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String SomeTransactionData { get; set; }
}
```

This is what is generated for me. Can I easily move the data in the original table to the other table?

```
public partial class test : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "CreditCardTransactions",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SomeTransactionData = c.String()
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("PurchaseOrder", "Transaction_Id", c => c.Int());
        AddForeignKey("PurchaseOrder", "Transaction_Id", "CreditCardTransactions", "Id");
        CreateIndex("PurchaseOrders", "Transaction_Id");
        DropColumn("PurchaseOrders", "Transaction_SomeTransactionData");
    }

    // Down() snipped
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can. Modify your `Up` method and prior to call `DropColumn` use `Sql` method with custom SQL transferring data from `PurchaseOrders` to `CreditTransactions` and fixing FK relationships.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like that is the only way. Done! :)